# Remover um item da lista de uma array em php?

Tags: php

PROBLEMA:

> Na array $reservado o item "09:00" não está sendo removido com o
>   método unset() dentro do foreach.

CÓDIGO:

```
$start = "09:00";  $end = "17:00";   $padding = 60;

$almoco = [ "12:00",  "13:00",  "14:00" ];
$reservado = [ "09:00", "15:00", "17:00", ];

$start_hour_reserve = date_create($start);
$end_hour_reserve = date_create($end);

$horas = date_diff($start_hour_reserve, $end_hour_reserve);

$intervalo = ($horas->h * 60) / $padding;

$appont[] = $start;

for ($i = 1; $i < $intervalo; $i++) {

    $start = date('H:i', strtotime("+{$padding} minutes", strtotime($start)));
    $appont[] = $start;
}

array_push($appont,  $end);


foreach ($almoco as $a) {

    if ($chave = array_search($a, $appont)) {
        unset($appont[$chave]);
    }
}
foreach ($reservado as $r) {

    if ($chave = array_search($r, $appont)) {
        unset($appont[$chave]);
    }
}

return $appont;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é com essa comparação:

```
if ($chave = array_search($r, $appont))
```

Nessa expressão o PHP irá converter o valor de `$chave` para [`booleano`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.boolean.php) e ao converter para booleano, os seguintes valores são considerados `false`:

- o próprio booleano `false`
- **o inteiro 0 (zero)**
- o ponto flutuante 0.0 (zero)
- uma string vazia e a string "0"
- um array sem elementos
- um objeto sem variáveis membros (somente PHP 4)
- o tipo especial NULL (incluindo variáveis não definidas)
  -o objeto SimpleXML criado de tags vazias

Qualquer outro valor é considerado `true`.

Quando a chave retornada por `array_search` for igual a `0` , no caso `9:00`, o zero é convertido em `false` não executando o código dentro do `if`.

Para resolver dever se usar a comparação estrita que além de comparar valores compara também os tipos.

```
    $chave = array_search($a, $appont); 
    if ($chave !== false) { 
        unset($appont[$chave]);
    }
```

Aqui `$chave`(0) é comparado com `false` e são tidos como iguais porém não são do mesmo tipo retornando `true`.

Incorporando no seu código:

```
<?php
$start = "09:00";  $end = "17:00";   $padding = 60;

$almoco = [ "12:00",  "13:00",  "14:00" ];
$reservado = [ "09:00", "15:00", "17:00" ];

$start_hour_reserve = date_create($start);
$end_hour_reserve = date_create($end);

$horas = date_diff($start_hour_reserve, $end_hour_reserve);

$intervalo = ($horas->h * 60) / $padding;

$appont[] = $start;

for ($i = 1; $i < $intervalo; $i++) {

    $start = date('H:i', strtotime("+{$padding} minutes", strtotime($start)));
    $appont[] = $start;
}


array_push($appont,  $end);


foreach ($almoco as $a) {
    $chave = array_search($a, $appont); // tira busca de dentro da comparação
    if ($chave !== false) { // Faz uma comparação estrita  
        unset($appont[$chave]);
    }
}


foreach ($reservado as $r) {
    $chave = array_search($r, $appont); // tira busca de dentro da comparação
    if ($chave !== false) { // Faz uma comparação estrita
        unset($appont[$chave]);
    }
}

//No código riginal é return $appont; eu usei o print_r($appont); somente para meus testes
print_r($appont); 
?>
```

Que retorna:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 10:00
    [2] => 11:00
    [7] => 16:00
)
```

[Link para o código](https://repl.it/repls/WorldlyDrabPayware)

Comment: Muito obrigado pela explicação, nota 10 Auguso